# Error in the values of the Rechart Stacked chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I'm trying to build a Stacked Bar Chart using the Pchart library. I attach the code below.

```js
function StackedBarChart({...props}){
    const {dataChart:{data,keys}} = props;

    const renderBars = () =>{
        return keys.map((item,index)=>(
            <Bar
                key={index}
                dataKey={item}
                stackId='a'
                fill={index%2?'blue':'red'}
                label
            />
        ))
    }

    return(
        <ResponsiveContainer width='100%' height={400}>
            <BarChart
                data={data}
                stackOffset='expand'
                >
                <XAxis dataKey="name" />
                <YAxis />
                {renderBars()}
            </BarChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
    )
}
```

When I output a value to each Bar I get incorrect signatures.[image] . Why is 2 Bar subscribed with the value 1 and not the remaining percentage. What is my mistake ?

my data

```js
const dataChart = {
  data: [{
      name: 'Page A',
      count: 4000,
      price: 2400,
    },
    {
      name: 'Page B',
      count: 3000,
      price: 1398,
    },
    {
      name: 'Page C',
      count: 2000,
      price: 9800,
    },

  ],
  keys: ['price', 'count']
};
```

Comment: Add example of data that you are providing into chart

Comment: So you want those bars to have values in percentages?

Comment: @OlegBrazhnichenko yes

Comment: I found a solution for you, working on formatting it, after that I'll post my answer with link to sandbox

Comment: @OlegBrazhnichenko Thank you, I will be waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this behavior, is that upper bar shown his top value, which is 1, so this is the sum of all bars stacked.

To avoid this situation I used valueAccessor and some formatting to get value of bar and count its percentage.

[Here is a link to working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bar-chart-with-positive-negative-forked-i24xxh) where you can see final result